# Apache Camel not returning http response after JSLT Transformation

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to get a http response out of the JSLT Transformer within Apache Camel.

Like in the given code sample

```
rest("/transform")
.post("/start")
.route()
.to("jslt:transform.jslt").transform().body
```

I want to return the body after the transformation.

But I always get an exception like

```
2022/03/23 14:51:09,842 [ERROR] [CamelHttpTransportServlet] - Error processing request
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
```

After adding a logger I can confirm that the jslt transformation into the body is working fine.

Plain responses like

```
rest("/say")
.get("/hello").route().transform().constant("Hello World");
```

work. I think it has to do with the implementation of the JSLT Transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your actual use case but assuming that you post a json payload to your endpoint then what you want to achieve can be done as next assuming that you use `camel-undertow`:

```
// configure rest-dsl
restConfiguration()
    // to use undertow component and run on port 8080
    .component("undertow").port(8080);
// The endpoint /transform/start calls the route `direct:jslt`
rest("/transform")
    .post("/start").consumes("application/json").to("direct:jslt");
from("direct:jslt")
    // Convert the payload to a String as only String or InputStream 
    // are supported by the component jslt
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    // Transform the body using the template transform.jslt available from 
    // the classpath
    .to("jslt:transform.jslt");
```

The result is directly set in the body of your message so it is what the rest endpoint will return back to the client in its body.

Comment: Your Idea seemed great but sadly doesnt work ... Somehow the JSLT Component seems to flush the output buffer.

The transformed body is available and can be sent to lets say a file , but sadly not returned to the post response 

I will take a look tomorrow into the apache camel jstl component

Comment: I tested the code above and it works like I described if it is not the case for you it means that your problem is elsewhere: version used, rest of the code causing side effects…

Comment: Thank you very much ... Its really only this piece of code , and Version is 3.14

Comment: I added more info to allow you to test what I proposed

Comment: Make sure that the `ExchangePattern` is set to `InOut` with `setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)`